# Power of a bounded linear map nullify each point implies the power is eventually zero

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I am working on a problem from my Qual

"Let $T:V\to V$ be a bounded linear map where $V$ is a Banach space. Assume for each $v\in V$, there exists $n$ s.t. $T^n(v)=0$. Prove that $T^n=0$ for some $n$."

My impression is that it looks like a algebraic problem. But I know nothing about $V$ (not fintely generated or something like that). So this one is off.

The hypothesis seems to be set up for the Uniformly Bounded Principle. Indeed, for each $v$, $\sup_n \{||T^n(v)|| \}$ is bounded, so by the principle, $\sup_n ||T^n||$ is bounded.

I'm stuck here. I don't think there is a relation between $||T^n||$ and $||T||$, even if there is, I cannot shake the feeling that the sequence $||T^n||$ may be eventually constant. I am hoping $||T^n||=0$ eventually but failed to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypothesis gives you that $V=\bigcup_n\ker T^n$, a union of closed subspaces. By Baire's Category Theorem, one of them contains a ball, and so it's equal to $V$.

Comment: okay i believe a closed subspace that contains a ball is the whole space. I can understand it geometrically. But how do I show it with a rigorous proof?

Comment: Suppose that $B_d(x)\subset M$, where $M\subset V$ is a subspace.  Now take any $v\in V$. Then $v'=x+\frac{\delta}{2\|v\|}\,v\in B_\delta(x)\subset M$. So $v=\frac{2\|v\|}{\delta}(v'-x)\in M$.

Comment: thank you. I figured i should put a coefficient there, but i don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing $X$ as a countable union of closed sets, and concluding that one of then contains a neighborhood.

Comment: i don't follow?

Comment: @TC : Martin spelled it out for you.